# Как заставить форму видеть комментарии?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Вообщем у меня есть:

контроллер: **Posts**

Модели: **Post**, **Comment**

Модель Post связана связью один ко многим с моделью Comment.

Пример:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments

end
```

---

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post

end
```

---

Миграция выглядит следующим образом:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text    :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

У меня есть Вьюшка для контроллера Post, она называется **show.html.erb**.
В ней я без проблем вывожу названия статей, например так:

```
<%= @post.name %>
```

Проблема в том, что на этой же странице в самом низу я хочу добавить форму для создания комментария, но никак не могу этого добиться. При попытке прописать нечто подобное:

```
<%= form_for @comments do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

Страница **show.html.erb** выдаёт ошибку #=>

```
undefined method `model_name' for Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

Можно ли заставить вьюшку одного контроллера видеть в себе значения другого контроллера?

В общем подскажите пожалуйста, как делать правильно или где я споткнулся?

Comment: Маршруты (`routes.rb`) ещё добавьте. Только те, что касаются `comments` (и во что вложены).

Comment: Вся проблема получается в том что у меня отсутствуют маршруты для комментариев ? А какими бы они выглядили ? Примерно кроме resources :commens

Comment: Нет, проблема не только в этом: в `form_for` указывается конкретный объект (или что-то другое, позволяющее идентифицировать маршрут). Но раз уж на то пошло, что в `@comments`?

Comment: Я наверное затуплю с ответом но в контроллер Posts я записал в экшен show:  @comments = Comment.all   И думал что через вьюшку Постов смогу обратиться к инстансной переменной comments и заставить форму сработать. Но похоже Posts контроллер просто не видит с чем работать (

Comment: Заранее скажу, что ошибаетесь и объект вы всё же получили, просто `form_for` отказывается его принимать. Но не слушайте меня, возьмите гем `pry`, сделайте в нужном месте `binding.pry` и проверьте сами.

Comment: А можно это решить без применения гемов ? Всё же не думаю что это такая сложная ситуация что бы гемы устанавливать.

Comment: `pry` это вариант отладчика, разрабатывать без отладчика очень грустно :) Он не решит вашу проблему, он поможет вам в неё вкопаться и увидеть, где что.

Comment: Ништяки по теме: [сайт `pry`](http://pryrepl.org/), [моё сентябрьское собеседование](https://github.com/D-side/helpdesk) (там есть пример реализации).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `@post.comments.build` в форме таким образом:

```
<%= form_for @post.comments.build do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

Либо вы можете инициализировать объект нового комментария в контроллере:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    @comment = @post.comments.build
  end
end
```

И в представлении:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

Запись `@post.comments.build` в этом случае будет аналогична записи `Comment.new post_id: @post.id`

Ссылка на документацию: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html - 4.3 has_many Association Reference