# Как правильно решается проблема с маршрутом?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подскажите пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть маршрут?

При отправке формы:

```
  <%= form_for :comment do |f| %>
      <%= f.label "Текст сообщения" %>
      <%= f.text_field :text %>
      <%= f.submit "send" %>
  <% end %>
```

Выбрасывает ошибку : **No route matches [POST] "/one-piece-729-van-pis-729-seriya"**

---

**rake routes**

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
             rails_admin        /admin                         RailsAdmin::Engine
                 lessons GET    /lessons(.:format)             lessons#index
                         POST   /lessons(.:format)             lessons#create
              new_lesson GET    /lessons/new(.:format)         lessons#new
             edit_lesson GET    /lessons/:id/edit(.:format)    lessons#edit
                  lesson GET    /lessons/:id(.:format)         lessons#show
                         PATCH  /lessons/:id(.:format)         lessons#update
                         PUT    /lessons/:id(.:format)         lessons#update
                         DELETE /lessons/:id(.:format)         lessons#destroy
                  animes GET    /                              animes#index
                         POST   /                              animes#create
               new_anime GET    /new(.:format)                 animes#new
              edit_anime GET    /:id/edit(.:format)            animes#edit
                   anime GET    /:id(.:format)                 animes#show
                         PATCH  /:id(.:format)                 animes#update
                         PUT    /:id(.:format)                 animes#update
                         DELETE /:id(.:format)                 animes#destroy
                  mangas GET    /mangas(.:format)              mangas#index
                         POST   /mangas(.:format)              mangas#create
               new_manga GET    /mangas/new(.:format)          mangas#new
              edit_manga GET    /mangas/:id/edit(.:format)     mangas#edit
                   manga GET    /mangas/:id(.:format)          mangas#show
                         PATCH  /mangas/:id(.:format)          mangas#update
                         PUT    /mangas/:id(.:format)          mangas#update
                         DELETE /mangas/:id(.:format)          mangas#destroy
                    root GET    /                              home#index
                comments GET    /comments(.:format)            comments#index
                         POST   /comments(.:format)            comments#create
             new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)        comments#new
            edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)   comments#edit
                 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)        comments#show
                         PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)        comments#destroy

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
  dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
      index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
        new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
     export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
       show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
       edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
     delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

---

Comment: Для более читабельного URL я использовал gem: Friendly_id. Что качается ошибки роута то она происходит если я форму ставлю во вьюшку контрллера Animes. И пытаюсь сделать пост запрос.

Comment: Вы лучше [предыдущий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495440/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8) отредактируйте, он же ровно об этом же.

Comment: Так форму у меня полуилось заставить видеть, просто обратился немного иначе:   <%= form_for :comment do |f| %> Проблема теперь в том что когда отправить запрос через форму пытаюсь теперь не выходит что то. У меня всегда с маршрутами беда (

Comment: Так ошибка на самом деле прежняя, вы заменили одну проблему на другую, вызванную тем же :D

Comment: Подскажите мне тогда мудрый человек )

Comment: Я уже в маршрут попробовал добавить даже:  resources :users do
    resources :comments
  end    Не помогает (

Answer (score 1):

`form_for`, получив первым аргументом **символ** (`:comment`), не пытается выводить из него URL, на который должны уйти данные из формы. Поэтому используется тот же самый URL, на котором браузер находится в данный момент, но используется HTTP-глагол `POST`.

Чтобы указать URL явно, нужно указать ему дополнительный параметр `:url`:

```
form_for :comment, url: <...>
```

---

Но вы переусложняете и такая форма записи вам не понадобится, пока вы отчётливо не осознаете обратного. Хелпер `form_for` максимально приспособлен для вывода маршрутов из **объектов моделей**. Он самостоятельно выясняет, запрос это на **создание** или **редактирование** (исходя из результата `model.persisted?`) и пробует построить по первому аргументу маршрут.

Если всё делать по конвенциям Rails с помощью `resources` и `namespace`, то первый аргумент для `form_for` можно построить по файлу маршрутов `routes.rb`.

```
resources :comments
#       VVV
form_for @comment
```

---

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
#       VVV      любое из
form_for [@post, @comment]
form_for [@post, @post.comments.build]
form_for [@post, Comment.new]
```

---

```
namespace :admin
  resources :posts
end
#       VVV
form_for [:admin, @post]
```